# Get DHCP Server address with only Powershell, like ipconfig /all

Tags: powershell, networking, cmd, dhcp, ipconfig

`Get-NetIPConfiguration` doesn't show DHCP server's ip address information. How can I do same as ipconfig /all but with PowerShell native tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this :

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "DHCPEnabled=$true" | Select DHCPServer
```

if you use Windows 7 / 2008 R2 or below :

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "DHCPEnabled=$true" | Select DHCPServer
```

Both will retrieve only interface with DHCP enabled, remove the filter if you want them all